# Java inner and outer loop confusion?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a function `isEvenSubset(12, 18)` which returns 1 if all the even factors of 18 lies in even factors of 12. This function return 1 for 12 and 18.

18=2,6(even factors)
12=2,4,6(even factors)

My code for this is given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(isEvenSubset(12, 18));
}

static int isEvenSubset(int m, int n) {
    int a=0;
    int factn=0;
    for (int i = 1; i <n; i++) {


        int factm=0;
        for (int j = 1; j <m; j++) {
            if(n%i==0&&i%2==0&&factm!=0){
                factn=i;
                System.out.println(factn+" "+factm);
                if(factn==factm){
                    a=1;
                }
                }
            if(m%j==0&&j%2==0){
            factm=j;                
            }                       
        }           
    }
    return a;
}
```

The result is not as expected. I am confused where in the code should I check `factn==factm`. Can somebody please give me some hint if using inner and outer loop is suitable here or should I look for any other approach.

Comment: You don't need two loop. A very simple (time consuming) approach for isEvenSubset(x, y) is to loop from z = 1 ... y, check if  z is even and a factor of y. If so check if z is also a factor of x. If not return 0 else continue the loop. After the loop add a return 1; statement. To speed up things a little, start your loop at 2 and increment by steps of 2.

Comment: Why return 0 and 1 instead of true and false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a nested loop here at all and are overcomplicating a simple thing. You want to know if all even factors of a number `n` are a subset of the even factors of another number `m`. Approach it like this:

1. Go through all even numbers `(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...)` up to `m`.
2. Check if your `n` can be divided by it.

   1. If yes, check if `m` can not be divided by it. If that's the case, return false.

And you are done. It's a simple 3 step algorithm. In code it could look like this:

```
for (int f = 2; f < m; f += 2)
{
    if (n % f == 0 && m % f != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

This is definitely not a fully optimized version and probably not even close to it. There are even simpler solutions to solve your problem. However it's still far less complex than what you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has an O(n^2) time complexity, which is very bad.

I'd make a function which calculates even factors of a number and returns them in an array.

So your main should call twice that function, returning two arrays. Then you should check whether all the numbers of m's array are contained within n's. That time complexity would be O(n).

Comment: how do you determine the time complexity of an algorithm?

Comment: It's mainly based on loops, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) wiki out.

Answer (score 0):

You confuse yourself cause your algorithm is to much complicated.

Just loop for all even number between 0 and the first number (here 18). For each one check if it divides the first number (18). If it does, check if it also divides the second number (12). If one that divide the first does not divide the second, exit and return 0 (or false). If you reach the end of the loop, all even divider of the first number also divides the second number so return 1 (or true).

```
static int isEvenSubset(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    for (int i=2; i<firstNumber; i+=2) {
        if(firstNumber%i == 0) {
           if(secondNumber%i !=0) {
               return false;
           }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```